# LINQ, use string[] in a query

Tags: linq

I have a query that looks something like this...

```
string value
            return DataContext.Tags.Where(t => t.Keys.Any(k => k.Ring.RingName == category))
                .Where(t => t.Keys.Any(k => k.Ring.Keys.Any(c => c.Tag.TagName == value)));
```

It works good, I love it. But it needs to do something extra. the 'value' string will actually be a string[] - is there any way to basically change the last lambda to say 'if the TagName matches anything found in this string[]'?

Comment: Why don't you combine the `Where` calls?

Comment: `.Where(t => t.Something && t.SomethingElse)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this: (Untested)

```
string[] values
return DataContext.Tags.Where(t => t.Keys.Any(k => k.Ring.RingName == category))
                       .Where(t => t.Keys.Any(k => k.Ring.Keys.Any(c => values.Contains(c.Tag.TagName))));
```

Comment: You just may be the greatest person that has ever lived. Thank you so much.

Comment: string[] does not have a Contains method.  Weird, maybe it does and it just doesn't show up in intellisense.

Comment: @SLak yeah, I noticed that if I just typed it out that it compiled fine, but when searching for the method using intellisense it didn't show that was valid.

Comment: It had contains when I tried it. I'll find out if it works and get back to you.

Comment: @BarretJ: You were probably looking at a `string` (non-array), which has LINQ extensions that don't show up in IntelliSense.  `string[].Contains` should appear in IntelliSense.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the declaration of value
    c =>(new List (value)).Contains(c.Tag.TagName)

If you can, can you declare it as List?